# python3 How do I continue a loop if no user input to update variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like a while loop to continue and only read the updated variable 'if' user adds one.

```
value = 2
print("Enter new/updated value: ")
while True:
   if():
      value = input()
   print(value)
```

output should be:

```
Enter new/updated value: 
2
2
2
2...
```

until I enter a new value '3' into the keyboard and then press enter (does not stop)

```
3
3
3
3...
```

or if I press 4 'and then enter' on the keyboards, I should get

```
4
4
4
4...
```

How update a variable similar to a chat session? Waiting for user input but without stopping the loop.

all I get are 2's and an updated value is never accepted.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a string in `input()` function to write a message. A break statment allow us exit from a loop and you need to validate your input before
Try this code :D

```
value = 2
while True:
  value = input("Enter new/updated value: ")
  if(value == 3):
    break;    
  else :
    print(value)
```

Comment: The loop still stops and waits for the next user input, using your code. Also, what happens if I want to change it to 4 instead of 3? I need the loop to keep going and only stop if user enters a value from the keyboard.

Comment: I thought that was the idea, but I guess, you want print for always the value that user wrote, but I thing the approach must be different you have to use a **thread** to keep printing and in the main thread have a for ever loop to keep listening for new inputs.
Is that what you want ?

Comment: Yes, I think we are on the same sheet of music now. This is very correct "use a thread to keep printing " and so is "have a for ever loop to keep listening for new inputs"

Comment: Thats rigth what I'd do is build two different python scripts (each script would be executed in their own terminal) using a **socket** first start the server printing the results defined in a variable an then in a client script connect the client and emit a new value in a for ever loop and finally with that message received from my client assign again the value to print

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are looking for something like **multi-threading** and **event listeners**, which is not as easy or beginner-friendly as you might expect... I think you should check out tutorials with those key words - or question if you *really* need functionality like that right now.